# Save xfce4 session from the command-line

Tags: command-line, xfce, session

I usually save the session with the graphical app [xfce4-session-settings](https://helpmanual.io/help/xfce4-session-settings/) (*Session* -> *Save Session*). Can this be also done from the command-line? How?

Comment: Looking at the source, the client appears to be in settings/session-editor.c . The part that saves seems to send a message through this: `xfsm_manager_dbus_client_checkpoint(manager_dbus_proxy, "", &error)` but it seems to also get asynchronous answers. Perhaps you can create a non graphical version from it? I mean a new program.

Comment: @A.B Thanks for the pointers, if there is no CLI command, I'll check it out.

Comment: More information on using dbus-send with the xfce4-session manager, including saving sessions, see this link: http://users.xfce.org/~kelnos/testing/xfsm-dbus-examples.txt.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[@guest123](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/258031/guest123) [pointed](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/401246/save-xfce4-session-from-the-command-line#comment716894_401246) to this [page](http://users.xfce.org/%7Ekelnos/testing/xfsm-dbus-examples.txt). To sum it up, you have to run this:

```
$ dbus-send --session --dest=org.xfce.SessionManager --print-reply \
      /org/xfce/SessionManager org.xfce.Session.Manager.Checkpoint string:""
```

It works for me with Xfce 4.12.